# How to access a function from a viewModel in another viewModel

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

I have 2 viewModels -

1. MainViewModel**
2. StorageViewModel

**StorageViewModel.kt**

```
class StorageViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val preferenceStorage: 
 PreferenceStorage, @ApplicationContext context: Context) : ViewModel() {

   ........
   //save last played song
   fun saveLastPlayedSong(song: Songs){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        protoDataStoreManager.saveLastPlayedSong(song)
     }
    }

  }
```

Now, I want to call the *saveLastPlayedSong* function in **MainViewModel**

**MainViewModel.kt**

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
private val musicServiceConnection: MusicServiceConnection,
private val storageViewModel: StorageViewModel
) : ViewModel(){ 

 .........
 
fun playOrToggleSong(
    mediaItem: Songs, toggle: Boolean = false
)
{
    //here, I want to call the function from StorageViewModel e.g 
    storageViewModel.saveLastPlayedSong(mediaItem)  
  }
}
```

How do I instantiate the "StorageViewModel" inside MainViewModel and whats the best way (Good Practice).

I'm using MVVM and Hilt.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it helped you? This can help other people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is usually a symptom of bad architecture.

If `StorageViewModel` is acting like a `Repository` it should not extend `ViewModel`. If it doesn't have connections to UI you can convert it to a repository class and that would solve your problem because it would just become an injectable singleton.

If `StorageViewModel` is connected to a Fragment (for example) you should take a reference to both viewmodels and pass data between them from the UI layer.

Something like:

```
class StorageFragment : Fragment {
  private val storageViewModel: StorageViewModel by viewModels()
  private val mainActivityViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

  //....

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //you can do this if the song saving is a UI related thing
    //just have playOrToggleSong accept a function as parameter
    //as success callback
    button.setOnClickListener {
      mainActivityViewModel.playOrToggleSong(...) {
        storageViewModel.saveLastPlayedSong(param)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about sharing the state of some UI? Would it be a bad architecture move having a reference of a ViewModel inside another? 

For instance, I have a sign-up process with a series of steps. I achieved that with a main fragment with a ViewPager and a main ViewModel. However, each step has its own ViewModel too. 

Seems a bit too bureaucratic for me to have both ViewModels in one fragment and use the fragment as a "bridge" between the two of them.